# Spring without getBean(..)

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, autowired

I'm trying to get a better understanding of the @Autowired annotations component scanning, but all the examples I found so far use context.getBean(..) at some point to get at least one Bean to start with.

I also read that doing that is considered bad practice , but I can't seem to find any information on how to do it without context.getBean(..)

Could somebody please enlighten me with an example and information on how to do this ?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

Define your bean in xml and use

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="com" />
 <mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Bean def

```
<bean id="processEngine" class="com.processEngine">
<property name="processEngineConfiguration" ref="processEngineConfiguration" />
</bean>
```

now you can get bean as following

```
@Autowired
private ProcessEngine processEngine;
```

Answer (score 0):

**how it works**

spring scans the bean's recipes either from xml or java configuration. then spring creates a `beanDefinitions` which are 'loaded' into `BeanFactory`. `BeanFactory` triggers a set of `BeanPostProcessors` (BPP) which are scanning classes for particular annotations like `Autowired`/`Resource`/`PostProcessor` and etc. and do appropriate actions. in case when your class contains `@Autowired` annotation, `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` would auto wire required field (dependencies), and when creation of an object is done and all BPP worked out, object is ready to be used by the app, from this point your code can get 'ready' objects from container.

there are some cases when you would need to access this beans from the code which is out of spring's control and not managed by container. in order to do so, you would need to get the `ApplicationContext` (container) and call `#getBean` specifying either name or type. using `applicationContext` directly is not a good practice because there are some problems that you can come to, f.ex. id of a bean might be changed and if you refer to bean by id then `NPE` would be thrown.

**configuration**

there are several approaches to configure spring to scan the classes for finding bean recipes. one would be defining `component-scan`, in this case classes which are located in the path that you've set and having any of valid spring annotations like `@Component`, `@Service`, `@Repository`, `@Controller` (for web container) would be considered. another way would be specifying each bean separately using `<bean>` or `@Bean`.

**examples.**
if you want to create a web app then you should see `DispatcherServlet` with `ContextLoaderListener` classes. this classes would boot your app and load everything according to configuration. f.ex. [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-hello-world-example/),
but if you want to create a desktop app, then you would end up with something like [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_hello_world_example.htm)

Answer (score -1):

From time to time (usually when not using Spring Boot), I use something along the lines of the following code:

```
public static <T> T autowire(ApplicationContext ctx, T bean) {
    ctx.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(bean);
    return bean;
}
```

In my `main`, I create an instance of the main application class that contains a few @Autowired annotations for the main services / entry points to my Spring application.